# How to pass lambda to macro?

Tags: lambda, lisp, common-lisp

I need to pass function and call it with specified arguments. How to properly pass lambda function to macro and avoid this error:

> APPLY: #'(LAMBDA (X) (+ X 1)) is not a function name; try using a symbol instead

Code:

```
(defmacro runner (fun &rest arg)
  (apply fun arg))
```

Call:

```
(runner #'(lambda (x) (+ x 1)) '(1))
```

What's wrong with my code? Tried something similar with `+` function and everything worked fine.

Update:
Program should call specified function for every argument and return result. Arguments are lists. So I should pass different functions which takes list.

```
(setq l1 (list 1 2 3))
(setq l2 (list 2 3 4))
(setq l3 (list 3 4 5))

(defmacro runner (fun &rest arg)
  ; some code
)

(defun summer (l)
  (reduce #'+ l))

(print (runner summer l1 l2 l3))
```

Just like this, but with arbitrary number of arguments.

```
(defun runner (l)
   (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (summer x)) l))

(print (runner (list l1 l2 l3)))
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this with a macro, not a function? Macros are used to expand code at compile time.

Comment: I need to create macro with syntax (do-this function (list1) (list2) ... (listn)) and do something like mapcar, but with lists and return new value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use backquote in the macro, so it expands into a call to the function at runtime, not compile time.

```
(defmacro runner (fun &rest arg)
   `(mapcar (lambda (a) (funcall #',fun a)) (list ,@arg)))

(setq l1 (list 1 2 3))
(setq l2 (list 2 3 4))
(setq l3 (list 3 4 5))

(defun summer (l)
  (reduce #'+ l))

(print (runner summer l1 l2 l3))

(print (runner (lambda (x) (+ x 1)) 1 3 4))
```

Since `runner` expects the first argument to be a function name, it adds the `#'` prefix itself before calling the function. So you should not use that before the `lambda` when you call it.

I changed `apply` to `funcall`, because the way you're calling `summer` shows that you expect each list to be passed as a single argument, not spread. And since your `lambda` expression expects its argument to be a single number, not a list, I passed the numbers as separate arguments, not wrapped in lists.

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/uHXjPp)

Comment: I think you last defmacro was intented to be a defun

Comment: Ok. But still I can't make macro to evaluate specified function for all arguments :(

Comment: Please update the question with what this is actually supposed to do. Show what it should expand to if you give multiple arguments.